# How to set Cache-Control HTTP header in OctoberCMS?

Tags: http, http-headers, octobercms

My application is returning `Cache-Control: no-cache, private` for all pages - how can I change this behaviour?

P.S.: It is not a PHP.ini problem, because changing session.cache_limiter to empty/public does not change anything.

Comment: are you in [debug mode](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#debug-mode)?

Comment: No, I'm not in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hook up an [event](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/events) listener to listen to specific events to set the headers

```
 Event::listen('cms.page.display', function ($controller, $url, $page, $result) {
        $headers = [
            'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=2592000, public',
        ];
        return Response::make($result, $controller->getStatusCode(), $headers);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to read about events - it that something like Middleware in Laravel? Is there something like Middleware in OctoberCMS?

Comment: You can register middleware in octobercms too, as it runs on laravel. The events are fired at specific points and you can hook it up anywhere basically, but usally you want to do it in the boot method of your Plugin. If you don't have a plugin yet, just make one so you can control the behaviour of your site from that plugin.`php artisan create:plugin Chevallier.SiteControl`

Comment: Thank you Tschallacka, now I know where to start :)